# My program with sockets randomly stopped working and gives me socket.timeout now?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-multithreading

I have been messing around with sockets to try get something working and have created a prototype. The idea is that a client can connect to the server, send a message and it will be echoed to all connected clients. I have added the server and client code but there is also a client2.py which is the exact same as the first client but sends "MESSAGE2" instead.

This was working and I moved on to making a better version (more efficient with error handling etc...) but then I came back and ran this and it no longer works?

server code:

```
import socket as sk
import selectors as sl
import types
import time

def accept(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print("accepted", conn, "from", addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    conn.settimeout(0.5)
    #this is really quite sloppy but basically this timeout
    #is required since the newly accepted
    #socket has not yet been registered
    conn.send("nick".encode("utf-8"))
    nick = conn.recv(1024)
    print(nick)
    print("registering", nick)
    sel.register(conn, sl.EVENT_READ|sl.EVENT_WRITE,data=(handle,nick))
    clientlist.append(conn)

def handle(key, mask):
    conn = key.fileobj

    data = key.data
    message = conn.recv(1024)
    broadcast(message)



def broadcast(message):

    #for key, mask in clients:

    #    print("sending",message,"to",key.data[1])
    #    key.fileobj.send(message)

    for client in clientlist:
        client.send(message)

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 65432

sel = sl.DefaultSelector()

server=sk.socket(sk.AF_INET,sk.SOCK_STREAM)
#this server socket will listen for clients
#and register them for communication
server.bind((host,port))
server.listen()
server.setblocking(False)

sel.register(server, sl.EVENT_READ, data=(accept,None))
#our listening socket is only interested in reading
#getting data from the clients to accept or decline it

clientlist=[]

print("initialisation complete")


while True:
    clients=sel.select()
    for key, mask in clients:
        callback = key.data[0]
        callback(key, mask)
```

client code:

```
import socket as sk
import threading as thr
import time

class Client:

    def __init__(self,hospor):

        self.nick = input("enter your nick: ")
        self.nickGiven=False

        self.hospor = hospor
        self.soc = sk.socket(sk.AF_INET,sk.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.soc.connect(hospor)


        msgThread = thr.Thread(target = self.msgLoop)
        receiveThread = thr.Thread(target = self.receiveLoop)


        receiveThread.start()
        msgThread.start()

    def msgLoop(self):

        while True:
            if self.nickGiven:
                msg = "MESSAGE"
                print("sending message")
                self.soc.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))
                time.sleep(10)


    def receiveLoop(self):

        while True:
            message = self.soc.recv(1024)
            if message == b"nick":
                print("received")
                self.soc.send(self.nick.encode("utf-8"))
                self.nickGiven=True
            else:
                print(message)

client=Client(("127.0.0.1",65432))
```

error message on the server side:

```
initialisation complete
accepted <socket.socket fd=268, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 65432), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 65011)> from ('127.0.0.1', 65011)
b'nick'
registering b'nick'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ottie_boi\Documents\00000 actual documents\0 School\0 Computer Science\0 NEA\repo\Actual-NEA\Testing\chatapp proto\v1\server.py", line 66, in <module>
    callback(key, mask)
  File "C:\Users\Ottie_boi\Documents\00000 actual documents\0 School\0 Computer Science\0 NEA\repo\Actual-NEA\Testing\chatapp proto\v1\server.py", line 26, in handle
    message = conn.recv(1024)
socket.timeout: timed out

Process finished with exit code 1
```

on the client side it just keeps looping the wrong part of code but doesn't crash or anything. I should mention that it successfully connects and sends one message back to the client which it receives but then the connection times out? It didn't use to do this so I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the socket for traffic before you have given it to select to handle the multiplexing.

```
def accept(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print("accepted", conn, "from", addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    conn.settimeout(0.5)
    #this is really quite sloppy but basically this timeout
    #is required since the newly accepted
    #socket has not yet been registered
    conn.send("nick".encode("utf-8"))
```

So I commented out the attempt to send data before giving it to select.

```
    # nick = conn.recv(1024)
    # print(nick)
    # print("registering", nick)
```

And removed the EVENT_WRITE, and tacked on `conn.send` post `.register`. EVENT_WRITE is for if you fill your outgoing buffer. To use this effectively you need to split your incoming and outgoing messaging so that each can respect the relevant event. At present your program flow assumes that if you receive a message you can write to everyone immediately. Likely, highly likely, but not necessarily true.

```
    sel.register(conn, sl.EVENT_READ,data=(handle,None))
    conn.send("nick".encode("utf-8"))
    clientlist.append(conn)
```

I tested with two clients running, your clients look to work for this simple case without modification. Using two threads inside a common class though, expect trouble. It looks like socket is thread-safe however writing from two threads to the same socket is going to nearly impossible to keep right.

In practice handling event loops well is non-trivial. I used to self write event loops with low level select handling in Perl. I switched to python when I discovered I could achieve the same functionality with asyncio with more readable code that was shorter and faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer its very helpful! I have a couple questions if you have time to answer:

1 - Could you explain in a little more depth how I would use EVENT_WRITE or point me to some documentation? Everything I've found has skimmed over it.

2-Why should I not use two threads in the same class?

3-Would you recommend I use asyncio? If so could you specify what I might specifically want to use and/or point me towards some documentation. I took a brief look into it and there is a lot of functionality it offers; I doubt I'll need it all .

Comment: 1/ EVENT_WRITE, I don't use it but the examples split ```for key, mask in clients``` into reads and writes. 2/ shared variables in threads require magic, this can bite. If your code is IO blocked event loops are lighter weight 3/ bottom of https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html